# Generate a multivariate normal vector

Tags: normal-distribution, dataset, random-generation, multivariate-distribution

I'm working in R and I was wondering, let's say I want to generate a random vector $X \in \mathbb{R^p}$, with $X \sim N(0,I)$ where $I$ is the identity matriz in $\mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$. The definition of a multivariate normal random vector is that each components are independent and $X_i \sim N(0,1)$ for all $i$. So, it should be any difference between

```
X = mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = rep(0,p), Sigma = diag(p))
```

and

```
X = rnorm(p)
```

¿?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two snippets of code will give you $N_p(0, I)$ realisations. They might not give you the same realisations even with the same seed because the code is different. Note that a single $N_p(0, I)$ realisation is essentially the same as $p$ $N(0,1)$ realisations.

In fact, we find that one realisation is just the other reversed!

```
> set.seed(1434) ##  time of day
> p  = 5
> MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = rep(0,p), Sigma = diag(p))
[1]  0.42352873 -1.08038282  0.07601366  0.17715223 -2.33229828
> 
> set.seed(1434) ##  time of day
> rnorm(p)
[1] -2.33229828  0.17715223  0.07601366 -1.08038282  0.42352873
```

This reversing means that using one in a piece of code rather than the other will give you different results (regardless of seed choice!). Of course, we can just apply a reordering to get identical results.

Upon inspection of the `MASS::mvrnorm` code  (just type `MASS::mvrnorm` straight into R - don't give any arguments) we can see that `MASS::mvrnorm` uses `rnorm` to generate random variables and then uses some matrix algebra to turn many realisations from $N(0, 1)$ into a single realisation from $N_p(\mu , \Sigma)$.

Comment: Thanks! So, when R needs to compute a random vector $X \sim N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ it computes a vector $Z \sim N_p(0,I)$ using rnorm(p) then makes $X = Z \Sigma^{1/2} + \mu$?

Comment: Yes this seems to be the case. In fact, I'd go to as far to say as most (all?!) multivariate normal generators do this

Comment: This would work only for independent $X_i$? I mean, if $\Sigma$ is not a diagonal matrix then the components of $X \sim N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ are not independent, right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're getting at? The transformation $\mu + \Sigma^{1/2}Z$ will gives a draw from $X$ whether then $X_i$ are independent or dependent, because $\Sigma^{1/2}$ will encode the same dependence structure as $\Sigma$

Comment: Yes, sorry. What I meant is that the $X_i$ are independent if and only if $\Sigma$ is diagonal, right? But rnorm(p) will give us independent copies of a standard normal. But yes, it's true that once I have my vector $X \sim N_p(0,I)$ (generated with rnorm(p)) I can use the transformation you said with the dependence given by $\Sigma$.